# Does Visual Studio AppCenter handle pushing updates to users?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

There's been a lot of changes to VS AppCenter and I'm not clear if it still pushes updates to the app to end users. I see a mention of pushing updates to beta testers but not clear if I can push my latest versions or updates to actual end users. Does anyone know definitively if update pushes to end users is still a feature.